# MS Access SQL Query optimization

Tags: sql, ms-access, optimization, query-optimization

Got this ugly piece of code that I'd like to make run faster. It worked alright until I had to add the setMotherTableValues() method aswell. As it is now I'm doing that mothertable-lookup about 48 000 times, and it's killing the program. Is there any way to improve this?
I don't have authority to change any columns in the databases.

```
public void populateMdbRecognitions(ArrayList<MdbRecognition> recognitions, String genid,
        String issueid, String issueexpression, String issuedetails,
        String tablename) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `" + genid + "`, `" + issueid + "`, `"
            + issueexpression + "`, `" + issuedetails + "` FROM " + tablename);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String gen_id = removeAmpsFromGenId(rs.getString(genid));
        String issue_id = rs.getString(issueid);
        String issue_details = rs.getString(issuedetails);
        String issue_expression = rs.getString(issueexpression);
        MdbRecognition recognition = new MdbRecognition(gen_id, issue_id,
                issue_details, issue_expression, tablename);
        recognitions.add(recognition);
    }
    for (MdbRecognition mdbRecognition : recognitions){
        setMotherTableValues(mdbRecognition);
    }

}

public void setMotherTableValues(MdbRecognition mdbRecognition) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `mandatory?`, category, subcategory FROM __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_7 WHERE issue_id ='" + mdbRecognition.getIssueId()+"'");
    while (rs.next()){
        mdbRecognition.setMandatory(rs.getString("mandatory?").trim());
        mdbRecognition.setCategory(rs.getString("category").trim());
        mdbRecognition.setSubcategory(rs.getString("subcategory").trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're doing?

- Select all the rows from an arbitrary
  table.
- Remove ampersands from gen_id.
- Save every row from that arbitrary table in a collection.

Then, for each item in that collection,

- Select three columns from
  __MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_7 by issue_id.
- Update values in that collection with values from those three columns.

Since you say you're just storing the strings to update a GUI, then you almost certainly need to change this:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `" + genid + "`, `" + issueid + "`, `"
        + issueexpression + "`, `" + issuedetails + "` FROM " + tablename);
```

to return exactly what your mdbrecognition object needs in order to do its job. You should see a breathtaking speedup if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You got it correct what I'm trying to do, thanks for making it clearer. I don't want to update any fields in the database, just fetch the values and add them to the collection. With that said, I'm going to read a bit about SQL UPDATE statements, if you wish your more than welcome to give me some concrete example.

Comment: @Emil: I'm just guessing about the UPDATE; you're the only one who knows what that mdbRecognition object is used for.

Comment: Oh right, sorry for being so unclear. The mdbRecognition object is used ONLY to store a bunch of String values, to be displayed in a GUI. So what I need to do is fetch the strings, and use those strings as arguments on the mdbRecognition setMethods.

Comment: You're executing a query inside a loop, generally not a recipe for good performance.  MOTHER_ISSUE_TABLE_7.Issue_id is indexed?

Answer (score 1):

Better to rewrite the first query, joining the mother issue table there.